# Word usage of "babysit"

Tags: grammar

Is there a chance that the expression "He is unfit to babysit" is about the baby to be babysat rather than the person who is supposed to babysit that baby? Thanks!

Comment: Is the baby unfit to be sat? A horse can be unfit to be trained. If you want that meaning, you need a passive construction.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is just the wrong adjective that I am using in this context? I mean, is it simply too rude and should be rather applied with animals or inanimate objects?

Comment: A car can be unfit to drive, a plane unfit to fly, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid the confusion by re-ordering the sentence to say something like: the baby is unfit to be left with a babysitter.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly could cause the confusion? The fact that the verb is both transitive and intransitive?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The baby is the object, not the subject, and therefore it would have be "He is unfit to be babysat" -- [a passive infinitive](https://www.first-learn.com/passive-infinitive.html).